# Why does QWindow not resize at half screen width?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

```
#include "editor.cpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    QApplication app(argc, argv);     
    QDesktopWidget *screen = QApplication::desktop();
    int height = screen->height();
    int width = screen->width();
    textEditor window;
    window.resize(width, height);
    window.show();
    window.resize(width/2, height);
    window.show();
    return app.exec();

}
```

Here why the width of window is n't becoming half?

On the other hand if i reverse the resize lines like this i still get a full size app.

```
    window.resize(width/2, height);
    window.show();
    window.resize(width, height);
    window.show();
```

here's the full code https://github.com/vinnusingla/TextEditor-in-QT

Comment: What are the values of `height` and `width` after you get them?

Comment: If you want some visualization of your resizing, you should use `QPropertyAnimation`. Otherwise you will get only final size.

Comment: Btw, this link may be usefull: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/application-windows.html#window-geometry

Comment: @Exa On debugging the height and width values are getting updated but the application size is not.